# Migrating MCF-application from Visual Studio 2005 to 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I have a really big and old windows application written in Visual Studio 2005 C++ using MFC. Since VS 2005 is not available anymore, I'm thinking about porting it to a newer Version of Visual Studio. Since Microsoft focusses on .net, I'm a bit afraid if the support for MFC is still there and strong enough to do so. Any experience or opinions about that?

Comment: In the non-express releases, they still have MFC. It's been redesigned since VS2005, but most of the classes and APIs should be the same or similar.

Comment: Most notable exception: MBCS support has been deprecated with VS2013. The MFC libraries for MBCS are available as a seperate download. See [Support for Multibyte Character Sets (MBCSs)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z097dxa.aspx) for details.

Comment: Thanks for your replys. I hope the redesign doesn't affect too much. Are things like the resource-editor still there?

MBCS is not used for unicode-support or German Umlaute I guess?

Comment: The resource editor is still there in VS 2013. What's more, the [MFC Class Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee748520.aspx) was resurrected in VS 2010. If your project is set to UNICODE (`_UNICODE` and `UNICODE` being defined) you won't have problems with missing MBCS support; you're not using it. MBCS is Microsoft's non-standard solution to encoding non-ASCII characters. German Umlauts can be encoded in either character set.